# Vaadin ExportTable URL to Excel save

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I wanted to export a table to Excel. I added the column of table with "addContainerProperty".

A row contains the URL.

I wanted this url to Excel export but that does not work. Url is exported as a string. but I wanted just as hyperlink.

I use ExportTable addon of Vaadin.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think this is as easy as you'd hope, since it's based on POI which requires to [create a hyperlink object](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Hyperlinks) but looking at the sources I have not find a way to inject a _cell factory_ of some sort. At this point I think your safest bet would be to extend `ExcelExport` the and override its `addDataRow` (~95% copy-paste) to create the hyperlinks for your desired column. Or just use POI yourself and create your own exporter. **P.S.** perhaps you could enhance the add-on and release a new version with its maintainer.

Comment: How can i addDataRow  override?
Musst i the source code download and work on that?

Comment: [Just as you'd do with any regular java class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html): extend `ExcelExport` and add a method with the same name, parameters and return type. It would probably benefit others if you'd fork the sources, modify the existing method, then push the changes to the repo and contact the maintainer to release a new version. Or ask him if he doesn't already have plans for this...

Answer (score 0):

```
        ExcelExport excelExport;
        excelExport = new ExcelExport(tblSearch, "Production Request Details");
        excelExport.setExportFileName("prduction_request_details_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".xls");
        excelExport.excludeCollapsedColumns();
        excelExport.setReportTitle("Production Request Details");
        excelExport.export();
```